# Ресурсы: почему new и create имеют разные пути?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть контроллер ArticlesController.

Есть ресурс articles.

Почему ***articles#new*** соответствует запрос ***GET /articles/new***, а ***articles#create*** соответствует запрос ***POST /articles***? Почему не ***POST /articles/new***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET /articles/new` - это, строго говоря, не является представлением ресурса (resource representation). Страничка, которая отдается по этому пути, нужна человеку. Он её заполнит и сможет сделать `POST /articles`. Машине, например, такая помощь не нужна, поэтому в каком-нибудь API такого роута просто не будет.

Почему делается `POST /articles`, а не `POST /articles/new`? Потому что такая конвенция.

Почему делается `GET /articles/new`, а не `GET /articles` (например)? Потому что `GET /articles` уже используется для списка статей. Вместо `new` можно было бы, конечно, использовать и другое слово. Например, `build` или еще что-нибудь. Но `new` тоже звучит неплохо и это как бы тоже конвенция уже.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вот почему я задал этот вопрос (возможно он был глупый): когда мы нажимаем кнопку submit, мы переходим на страницу /articles и с нее поидее идет редирект уже на другую в случае успеха. Но если пользователь ввел некоректные данные, то мы выдаем предупреждение (что например поле незаполнено) и остаемся на той же странице, т. е. на /articles. Мне кажется это нелогичным.

Comment: Просто я привык к Yii и по-этому возникают такие вопросы

Comment: @fiftin: это да, ресурсы в рельсах и ресурсы которые из REST - это две разных концепции. Поначалу может казаться неожиданным, а потом привыкнешь :)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что **POST** запрос используется для отправки определенного объекта и url **/articles** нужен для идентификации ресурса **Article.rb** в ActionDispatch.

A **GET /articles/new** нужен для того, чтобы получить от сервера требуемую отрендеренную вьюху. И если внимательно посмотрите на **app/views/articles**, то не увидите **create.html.erb**